How to find costs to an integer program that maximize integrality gap
This is a cross-post from the Operations Research stackexchange.
Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. For $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let
\begin{align} \text{ILP}(c) = \max \quad & c^\top x \\ \text{s.t.} \quad & x \in \mathbb{Z}^n \\ & A x \leq b \end{align}
be the optimal value of a solution of the integer linear program defined by $A$, $b$, and $c$, and let
\begin{align} \text{LP}(c) = \max \quad & c^\top x \\ \text{s.t.} \quad & x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\ & A x \leq b \end{align}
be the optimal value of a solution of the corresponding LP relaxation.
I am interested in the problem
\begin{align}
\max \quad &\frac{\text{LP}(c)}{\text{ILP}(c)} \tag{MaxGap} \\ & c \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
i.e. finding costs $c$ that maximize the integrality gap.
I think this would be called a non-linear, bilevel optimization problem.
I tired to reformulate this problem as an mixed integer linear program and I got the following:
\begin{align}
\max \quad & g \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & g \geq 1 \\
& c \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
& g \cdot i \leq l \\
& l \leq \text{LP}(c) \\
& \text{ILP}(c) \leq i \enspace .
\end{align}
The inequality $l \leq \text{LP}(c)$ can be reformulated as $l \leq c^\top x$ with additional variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and additional constraints $Ax \leq b$.
The inequality $\text{ILP}(c) \leq i$ can be written as $c^\top y \leq i$ for all $y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $Ax \leq b$.
But this formulation is problematic because of the non-linear parts $i \cdot g$, $c^\top x$, and $c^\top y$ and because of the for all that results from $\text{ILP}(c) \leq i$.
Am I missing something? Is there a way to reformulate (MaxGap) such that there is any chance of solving it for at least small $n$ and $m$?
Is there any better way for computing the maximal integrality gap?
I think another method would be to find the facet inducing inequalities of the polytope defined by the ILP and compute for each such inequality how much it can be violated by a solution to the LP. However, this approach is also impractical as enumerating facets of an integer polytope is often not possible.
